# How to disable input in datalist?

Tags: php, html

I want to block the user to input I just want him to choose only from the list
I tried disable and readonly but this will disable my list and I don't want that.
This is my code

```
<div class="form-group row justify-content-center" id=" input-champs " style="margin-left:;" ><!-- grossistee --> 
   <label for="grossiste" class="col-2 col-form-label"></label>
  <div class="col-3">
    <input type="text" list="list-gro"  placeholder="Grossiste1"  id="g_name1" name="g_name1" class="form-control">
    <datalist id="list-gro">
        <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultg)) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['g_name']; ?>"><?php echo $row['g_name']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </datalist>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [html5 datalist to select only predefined options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30499199/html5-datalist-to-select-only-predefined-options)

Comment: The described behaviour reminds me of select elements. Why a datalist element in this case?

Comment: @AndreaOlivato no it deosn't thank you .... I don't want let the user type in anything by himself but select one of the options

Comment: @Marcel i used datalist because i don't know how to use a select element with database query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the living standard spec of the [datalist](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-datalist-element) element:

> Each option element that is a descendant of the datalist element, that is not disabled, and whose value is a string that isn't the empty string, represents a suggestion. Each suggestion has a value and a label.

Conversely, this means that a user can enter anything he wants. The datalist element only contains suggestions that the user can use, but does not have to.
For your puprose I 'd suggest a select element. A select element dictates strict values for the user to use.

```
<label for="my-select">My Select</label>
<select name="my-select" id="my-select" required>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
    <?php foreach ($databaseresult as $row): ?>
        <option value="<?= htmlspecialchars($row['value']) ?>">
            <?= htmlspecialchars($row['label']) ?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

Comment: i replaced this ""<?= htmlspecialchars()"" with <?php echo..... and done ... thank you so much marcel

Comment: i tryed this and it worked for m 
<select type="text" list="list-gro" placeholder="Grossiste2" autocomplete="off" id="g_name2" name="g_name2" class="form-control">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
    <?php foreach ($resultg as $row): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['g_name']; ?>">
            <?php echo $row['g_name']; ?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</select>

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use `select` in place of `input` as you dont want the user to type in anything from himself/herself.

You can do like this to implement `select` with database query

```
<select name="g_name1" id="g_name1" class="form-control">
  <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultg)) { ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $row['g_name']; ?>"><?php echo $row['g_name']; ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: but if i do that if the user doesn't select it and when he presses submit ... in the database it will insert by default the first value ....
i want him to choose one from the list or nothing this field is not required

Comment: you can use form element along with `required` attribute so that the value is not left empty

Comment: this feild can't be required this is the problem

Comment: you can add an empty option juste before your loop with null as value and check whether the value is null or not. if null then dont do anything else insert data